# Join causes Cartesian Product

Tags: mysql, sql

I preformed a left join on two tables, however cartesian products were produced while it doesnt on others. The sample result of the query can be seen in the pic below.
[image]

The query current query is:

```
SELECT 
    R.Region, 
    C.CountryName, 
    D.Year, 
    I.Income, 
    D.Completion_Rate AS 'Completion Rate', 
    D.Pupil_Teacher_Ratio AS 'Pupil-Teacher Ratio'
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        C.CountryCodeC AS 'CountryCode', 
        C.YearCC AS 'Year', 
        C.Completion_Rate, 
        R.Pupil_Teacher_Ratio
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
            CountryCode AS 'CountryCodeC', 
            Data AS 'Completion_Rate', 
            YearC AS 'YearCC' 
        FROM 
            DataByYear 
        WHERE 
            SeriesCode = "SE.SEC.CMPT.LO.ZS" 
            AND YearC >= "2011%") C
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT 
                CountryCode AS 'CountryCodeR', 
                Data AS 'Pupil_Teacher_Ratio', 
                YearC AS 'YearCR' 
             FROM 
                DataByYear 
             WHERE 
                SeriesCode = "SE.SEC.ENRL.LO.TC.ZS" 
                AND YearC >= "2011%") R
        ON C.CountryCodeC = R.CountryCodeR) D, 
    CountryRegion R, 
    Country C, 
    CountryIncome I
WHERE 
    R.CountryCode = D.CountryCode 
    AND R.CountryCode = C.CountryCode
    AND I.CountryCode = D.CountryCode
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it. Thank you!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.  In addition, you have commas in the `FROM` clause -- that is really bad syntax for a cross join.

Comment: you should add db schema and, if possible, convert the image into text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are also looking to join on `Year` for all of your queries. If you don't specify a year then each year will get joined with all other years and inflate your values. So you should add a condition like:

```
A.Year = B.Year
```

throughout your query.

Answer (score 1):

try using `INNER JOIN` instead of left join.